# CKEditor toolbar does not appear as configured

Tags: wysiwyg, toolbar

under `/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full` I have configured the CKEditor toolbar to appear in `Full`. However, when I edit my content in `Full HTML`, the toobar looks incomplete (see screenshot).[image]

**EDIT 1**

The toolbar configured in `/admin/config/development/performance`
[image]

Comment: `the toobar looks incomplete` what are you missing? Looks complete to me. Can you show a screenshot of your config page toolbar?

Comment: @NoSssweat Please see **EDiT 1** above particularly, I'm missing the font and textt size selectors

Comment: did you click on the blue `Full` link above? if you didn't, perhaps you are editing/viewing the Advanced toolbar.

Comment: @NoSssweat yes, I did click on it

Comment: hmmm did you flush/clear the cache?

Comment: @NoSssweat yep, I did as well

Comment: hmm thats is very odd, maybe try disabling and uninstalling and re-installing the module.